# why Aarray initialize is not allowed here in android studio

Tags: android

am try to convert String to my language from yahoo weather service and actually am  new in android . when i put

```
String days = {"الاحد", "الاثنين", "الثلااء", "الاربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت"};
```

i get mean errors and read line .

```
package net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.data;

import android.widget.TextView;

import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.R;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.WeatherActivity;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Condition implements JSONPopulator {
    private int code;
    private int temperature;
    private int highTemperature;
    private int lowTemperature;
    private String description;
String days = {"الاحد", "الاثنين", "الثلااء", "الاربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت"};
    private String text;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public int getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public int getHighTemperature() {
        return highTemperature;
    }

    public int getLowTemperature() {
        return lowTemperature;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return days;
    }
    public String gettext() {return text;}

    @Override
    public void populate(JSONObject data) {
        code = data.optInt("code");
        temperature = data.optInt("temp");
        highTemperature = data.optInt("high");
        lowTemperature = data.optInt("low");
        description = data.optString("text");
        days = data.optString("day");
        text = data.optString("text");

    }

    @Override
    public  JSONObject toJSON() {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

        try {
            data.put("code", code);
            data.put("temp", temperature);
            data.put("high", highTemperature);
            data.put("low", lowTemperature);
            data.put("text", description);
            data.put("day", days);
            data.put("text", text);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return data;

    }
}
```

i would like to use strings day so there any way ? i hope there some help with a code :)

Comment: use the constructor to initialise the array

Comment: @AshishSinha give me example please

Comment: `String[] days` is an array

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh 
its same Aarray initialize is not allowed here

Comment: can you put a complete error snapshot or details and make sure you are using `String[] days = {"...."};`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh check error https://d.top4top.net/p_566u3wci1.png

Comment: `optString` will give you a string , you cannot have `days` declared as array and later using it as a `String`

Comment: i get error Incompatible types

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh so what the solution ?

Comment: you need to give information about what exactly you are trying to achieve here, edit your post to add clarity

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh actually i dont have a good language to explain , i have weather data service , and the days of week in json coming in English language i want to convert days of week in Arabic language . do you want give you source  code to take look and maybe you find the solution

Comment: if it is a single day then you can simply create a `Map` where keys will be your english names and value will be arabic name ,then simply use `get` function to retrieve the corresponding arabic value

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh unfortunately its 7 days . and my app finally his 90% complete just the problem days of week

Comment: then you have to loop through your `days` jsonarray and use get function of created map to get the corresponding values

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh why not take look on code ?

Comment: even i can give you teamvid @Pavneet_Singh